# Select database records which are m:n-related to records from another table

Tags: sql, database, relationship

I'm trying to select all records from table A which are related to X certain records in table B (m:n relationship).
These are my tables:

> hs_hotels:
>   id - name
>
> hs_hotel_options:
>   hotel_id - option_id
>
> hs_options:
>   id - name

Now I have, let's say 3, IDs of certain records from table hs_options and I'm looking for all records from table hs_hotels which are related to the given records from hs_options and also fit some other conditions. At the end, I want a set of records from hs_hotels.

This is my current attempt:

```
SELECT `hs_hotels`.*
FROM `hs_hotels`
RIGHT JOIN `hs_hotel_options` ON (`hs_hotels`.`id` = `hs_hotel_options`.`hotel_id`)
WHERE `hs_hotel_options`.`option_id` IN (1, 3, 5)
GROUP BY `hs_hotel`.`id`
```

1, 3 and 5 are IDs of records from table hs_options. This just selects all records from hs_hotels which are related to 1 of the 3 given records from hs_options instead of all 3 records. The problem I have is that I don't know how to solve this. I could try to select all records `WHERE option_id = 1 AND option_id = 3 AND...` but of course this won't work.

Do you have any ideas how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you perform outer join in this query? If there is no any hotel with specified id in hs_hotel then there will not have to be any records with specified hotel_id in hs_hotel_option. As I understand it is a business rule requirement. Try to remove outer join, and use here just inner join, because the structure of the query that you want to perform is correct

Comment: You had RIGHT JOIN but then you did a WHERE clause on the "RIGHT" table. This has the effect of turning the RIGHT JOIN into an INNER JOIN. What was the effect of the RIGHT join you were hoping for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to Tom H.'s you need to count the options and then associate it with the hotel.

You can use `inner join` `exists` or `IN`. I chose `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Hotels H
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT
         hotel_id
       FROM
        hs_hotel_options
      WHERE 
        option_id IN (1, 3, 5)
      GROUP BY 
         hotel_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 3) req_options
   ON h.hotel_id = req_options.hotel_id
```

Comment: Is it ok to use having clause without group by?

Comment: Thank you, I implemented yours and it seems to work very well.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    <column list>
FROM
    Hotels H
WHERE
    (   SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM
            Hotel_Options HO
        WHERE
            HO.hotel_id = H.hotel_id AND
            HO.option_id IN (1, 3, 5)
    ) = 3
```

I don't know if this subquery syntax is supported under your RDBMS or not.

Comment: I'll test your version soon and will make some performance benchmarks.